# QML: Button that opens a window from ApplicationWindow

Tags: qt, qt5

I have a button called Adavanced Settings in my ApplicationWindow. OnClicked I want it to open a Window, where I will have ComboBox, TextEntry, etc. Can anyone tell me how to proceed with the onClicked. Currently I have:

```
ApplicationWindow{

...

    Button {
        text: "Advanced Settings"
        onClicked: {
            var component = Qt.createComponent("PopUpSetingsWindows.qml");

        }
    }
}
```

PopUpSetingsWindows.qml

```
Window {
    id:secondwindow
    width: 800
    height: 480
    title: "Second"

    Text {
      text: "Hello World"
    }
}
```

But the window doesn't show. Did I understand everything wrong ?

Comment: I found a solution in this link https://forum.qt.io/topic/30120/solved-launch-a-child-qml-window-from-a-parent-qml-window/3.

Comment: If you found an answer to your question, please post it here and accept it so it can be used by others in case that they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in the link provided in my comment above. Here are the details for my example problem and also in case the link gets inactive in future.

```
ApplicationWindow{
id: root
property variant win;  // you can hold this as a reference..

...

Button {
    text: "Advanced Settings"
    onClicked: {
        var component = Qt.createComponent("PopUpSetingsWindows.qml");
        win = component.createObject(root)
        win.show();
        }
    }
}
```

QML file remains unchanged